# How can I attach three oscillating sprinklers to one hose?

Tags: sprinkler-system

Is there a way I can plug three oscillating sprinklers into one hose? I have a big backyard and I don't want to stand there and water it every morning. I have one sprinkler because I only have one tap/hose in the backyard. I was wondering if there is a way to add multiple sprinklers to it.

This is the kind of sprinkler I have currently:

[image]

Comment: as the answers show, you can easily get splitters at nearly any home/garden/hardware store. Note that you can't run them all at once, though, as you won't have enough water pressure. You'd still have to go out and turn them off/on as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can purchase a Y adapter that fits on the tap and gives you two feeds:

[image: Y Adapter]

You can also chain these to give you 3 feeds by using 2 adapters.  This however requires a lot of hose. You can also find sprinklers that have an IN and OUT feed so that you can daisy chain them:

[image: Sprinkler with in and out]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/91634_4.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, there is an end cap you can remove and then add another hose to the next sprinkler.  This is often preferred as it requires less and shorter hoses all over the place.

Answer (score 5):

Use a hose splitter, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PSFLT2) from Amazon:

[image]

Comment: Be certain to drain it before it goes freezing outside. Ice will shatter the plastic housing on these.